# Hadoop.conf.configuration error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to execute a Java class by executing a `jar` file through `java -jar abc.jar` but whenever I execute it I get error as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
```

My `hadoop-env.sh` file in `/etc/hadoop/conf` directory contains `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` as:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="/home/cloudera/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/cloudera/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar:hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"
```

In the Java code I have certain imports like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
```

and I think it is not able to get the definitions of these at run time. 
what is causing these errors and how do I resolve this issue?

**NOTE:** I am new to hadoop and as such I do not know what and how to set different environment variables needed. Any example will be helpful for me.

**UPDATE:** After I executed `java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH:abc.jar:/home/extra_jars/* mypackage.classname` I get error as `java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /user/example`

In my code I am executing `fs.copyFromLocalFile(false,true,sourcePath,targetPath);` and the `targetPath` is `/user/example/ex1.csv`. I am unable to understand why this error is coming even though my `/user/example` has full red-write permissions.

Comment: try to include the classpath: `java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH -jar abc.jar`

Comment: when I execute `java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH -jar abc.jar `I get error as `Error: Could not find or load main class abc.jar`

Comment: what about `java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH:abc.jar your.package.YourClassName`

Comment: @Arbi  the previous error of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration`

Comment: The error `java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /user/example` usually means that the user you are running the program as does not have enough privileges to create a directory `/user/example`. If this is a CDH or HDP cluster try running the program as `hdfs` user or if this is a apache hadoop cluster try running as superuser (usually `hadoop` user).

Comment: @AshrithM I am running a CDH cluster. How do I run the program as `hdfs` user? I mean how do I switch user from command line?

Comment: You could use sudo like this `sudo -u hdfs java -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH:your.jar yourpackage.yourclassname`

Comment: @AshrithM I tried this way but still same `Mkdirs failed to create` error

Comment: @AshrithM I found this post on so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path but couldn't understand the accepted answer here

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path might shed more light

Comment: @AshrithM The accepted answer says that the file is on local disk but on my local disk there is no directory `/user/example`. This exists in `hdfs` only

Comment: I created the `/user/example` directory on my local system and executed the jar again and it ran successfully. It is not writing to the `hdfs` even though the code uses `copyFromLocal()` which writes to hdfs

Comment: Do you have the folder `/user/example` created in HDFS? Or are you trying to create them in the code? If in code, as someone pointed out, it could be an access problem. Also check that you have the datanode and namenode directories set in config.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Yes I already have created the the `/user/exampl` in HDFS. The namenode I using is same as mentioned in the `core-site.xml` file.

Comment: Namenode and datanode folders should be defined in hdfs-site.xml. Can you show us that file.