# Mac OS Hadoop: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

When I run a jar file in Hadoop, I run into a problem.

In the terminal, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/5_/hxmqt1090j1g1tqm485hr7tw0000gn/T/hadoop-unjar898783490589040837/META-INF/LICENSE (Is a directory)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue, my code written in scala, and I wanna run the jar on hadoop with command:
like:

```
./bin/hadoop jar testing/learning-yarn-1.0.0.jar com.learning.yarn.simpleapp.SimpleApp
```

It report error:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/dy/kgryx_f11g1fdqpcnc8jl
m840000gp/T/hadoop-unjar5812913115154946721/META-INF/LICENSE (Is a directory)

I modify my maven configuration base on [Hadoop java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /some/path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path)
And now soved it.

My maven shade plugin configuration is like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <!-- <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>-->
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheLicenseResourceTransformer">
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>license/*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.typesafe.akka</artifact>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>reference.conf</include>
                                </includes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

if I add true it will report scala class not found, comment out this config worked.
Good luck.