# Mkdirs failed to create hadoop.tmp.dir when running word count example for hadoop 1.2.1 version on windows 7 using cygwin

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin

I am new to hadoop.I have installed hadoop using cygwin in windows 7. Now I am trying to run `Wordcount` example. when using the command:-

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar WordCount /user/Taniya/input /user/Taniya/output
```

An error is shown:-

> Mkdirs failed to create >\cygwin64\home\Taniya\tmp\hadoop-cyg_server

I have looked through the web and the solutions provided are not clear to me. Looking for a solution that is clearly stated.

Comment: It might be the permission issue please have a look at, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path

Comment: Check if you have permissions to write into local path: \cygwin64\home\Taniya\tmp\hadoop-cyg_server