# Hadoop create jar from maven project cause NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop

Hadoop 2.7.1
I have an Eclipse (maven) project.
I'm able to run wordcount hadoop example, so hadoop is correctly configured.
If i try to instance an object that uses Model class from Apache Jena at runtime the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model
        at hadoop.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

The same object (the one which uses Jena) works in a standalone (no hadoop) project.
The same error happen when i try to run stats hadoop example.
To create the jar i run:

```
mvn clean package
```

It seems that if i try to use classes from other libs, those classes will not be "included" in the generated jar.
Where i'm wrong? Any suggestions? Now i'm out of ideas!

EDIT #1:

I tried to compile with:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

using this assembly config:

```
<assembly>
  <id>hadoop-job</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>${groupId}:${artifactId}</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <includes>
        <include>${groupId}:${artifactId}</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

but i'm still facing the same problem.

EDIT #2:
In my case this worked:

In pom.xml include this plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>license/*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And then

```
mvn clean compile package
```

(solution taken from @Garry in post: [Hadoop java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /some/path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path) )

Now it works, but take a lot of time in "unzip" process. Any known workaround?

Comment: create jar-with-dependencies. use maven plugin for created that. with this command : mvn clean compile assembly:single