# Hadoop java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /some/path, when running mapreduce job on mac osx

Tags: macos, hadoop, jar

When I run my MR job on mac osx, I face on the following exception:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /var/folders/9m/w_vzzmtx0rq0tt9whf_r4yhr0000gn/T/hadoop-unjar7688811202881231043/META-INF/license
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.ensureDirectory(RunJar.java:128)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:104)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.unJar(RunJar.java:81)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:209)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

According [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path), people gave alternative way to remove META-INF/LICENSE from jar file. I feel it seems temporary solution.

I think it will resolve if path trying to store tmp files below:

```html
/var/folders/9m/.../META-INF/license
```

I checked permission and tried to change "hadoop.tmp.dir" value in core-site.xml, but it doesn't work for me.

PS. I know the issue is caused case-insensitive property for osx. Then, I am working with directory mounted disk image, which is case sensitive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which MR job are you running?

Comment: My job is to write files in HDFS after parsing.

Comment: Check below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32698951 That will fix your problem.