# Hadoop create file in java throws exception: Mkdirs failed to create

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to create a file in Hadoop using Java client (just a test case). The exception below was thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /app2/speed (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/cpu-local/NetBeansProjects/hdoops) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:450) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787) 
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:776) 
    at com.abc.hadoop.Test.main(Test.java:35)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hadoop java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /some/path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522835/hadoop-java-io-ioexception-mkdirs-failed-to-create-some-path)

Comment: I check that case already. But it nope.

Comment: Is that an hdfs location, or local filesystem?

Comment: If local, you try to run `mkdir /app2/speed` in your regular Terminal, and it'll likely fail with permission denied because you're making a root directory

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becase of failing in create FileSystem through java client, all you need is setting your java client appropriate the hadoop configuration (in file config).

```
Configuration hadoopConfig = new Configuration();
hadoopConfig.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000/");
hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
hadoopConfig.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
```